# why do we need to prove that the limit of a contraction is a fixed point in the contraction mapping theorem

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

[In this chapter](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/book/ch3.pdf) they first prove that iteratively applying a contraction is a cauchy sequence. Since the metric space is complete we know that sequence converges, and it does so to a unique point. So why do they then additionally prove that the point of convergence is a fixed point of the contraction, isn't this already implied by the proving the sequence is cauchy. I feel like it's more of a corollary since it applies to any arbitrary function that is continuous in the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why do they then additionally prove that the point of convergence
> is a fixed point of the contraction

Because that's what the theorem states, and therefore, that's what the proof should conclude with.

> isn't this already implied by the original proof.

What do you mean by "original proof"? There is only one proof and it can be divided into the following parts:

1. Prove that the sequence, defined by $x_{n+1} = T(x_n)$ converges.
2. Prove that **if** a sequence, defined by $x_{n+1}=T(x_n)$, converges, then the limit of the sequence is a fixed point of $T$.
3. Conclude from 1 and 2 that $T$ has a fixed point.
4. Prove that $T$ can have at most one fixed point.
5. Conclude from 3 and 4 that $T$ has exactly one fixed point.

Now, sure, alternatively, the authors could cite point number 2 above as a separate lemma, and prove it *before* proving the main theorem, but I'd say it's cleaner this way, for two reasons:

- The proof is short, so splitting it into subtheorems would not help readability
- The lemma itself is not all that interesting.

---

Edit:

It is, of course, also possible to prove point 3 directly from 1 and from the fact that $T$ is continuous. However, this would most probably lead to a proof that is harder to follow, and possibly even longer than original.

But the mere fact that you can prove something *without* a particular sub-lemma does not mean that that particular lemma is "useless" for the proof. Technically, every proof in mathematics can be trimmed down to base principles, but at a great cost of readability.

Comment: Sorry I could have made myself a bit clearer, doesn't proving 1. (the sequence is cauchy) imply 2.?

Comment: @questions You also need that $T$ is continuous.

Comment: i mentioned the continuity requirement in my post, so that should mean 2.) is really a corollary of proving 1.)  right?

Comment: @questions No. It is not a corrolary. $A$ is a corrolary of $B$ if the logical statement $B\implies A$ is true, and that is simply not the case here.

Comment: @questions The statement 2 is a corrolary of **two** separate facts. One, the sequence $x_n$ converges, and **two**, $T$ is continuous. Without continuity of $T$, you cannot infer 2 from 1 alone.

Comment: @5xum but in this case T refers to a contraction which is continuous on the domain by definition, so proving 1 would be sufficient surely.  2 doesn't prove that T is continuous it just states that if T is continuous then the point of convergence is a fixed point. Since we know that T is both continuous (by definition) and induces a cauchy sequence it directly implies 2.

Comment: @questions You cannot, logically, infer point 3 from **only** from point 1. If you only prove point 1, you have not proven that $T$ has a fixed point. That's why you either *need* point 2, or you need some other way of proving point 3 directly from point 1. But any other way will probably be longer, which is why the proof you linked went the way it went. If you think the proof could be significantly shortened, I invite you to try it, write down the shorter proof, and I can go through it to see if it is logically sound.

Comment: @5xum Using just 1, and the fact that T is continuous within the domain. Let x' be the point of convergence if T(x') =/= x' then we could never converge to x' therefore, x' must be a fixed point

Comment: @questions OK, great. You did it, you proved point 2. So... what's your question?

Comment: @5xum I just wanted to know whether 2. was necessary.  As you said $A$ is a corollary if $B \implies A$ which i believe makes 2. a corollary. I don't feel like 2 contributes to the theorem it seems like it was more to just help with clarity but I wasn't entirely sure so I decided to ask

Comment: @questions If you do not feel like 2 contributes to the theorem, feel free to write the proof without it, and compare the two proofs. I can almost guarantee one will be much less clear. And adding clarity **is** a contribution to the theorem. I mean, you can prove the theorem from first principles, so basically, anything above first principles is only there to add clarity.

Comment: @5xum I do agree with that, if you append your answer to summarise our discussion i'd be happy to select your answer. and if you could do so without modifying the original answer too much because I do also like the clarity of your original answer in highlighting the steps

Comment: @questions I added another paragraph to my answer, I think it now has all you asked.